Как отключить проверку сертификата в argocd
argocd поднят в kubernetese и отдельно поставил еще argocd cli. Всё успешно установилось, подключил локальный гитлаб и тестовые yaml спокойно деплоятся. Проблема в попытке пулить образы из локального реестра докера.
"apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: web-app-deployment
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:

 app: web-app
Use code with caution.
template:
metadata:

 labels:

  app: web-app

spec:

 containers:

 - name: web-app-container

  image: IP/louislam/uptime-kuma:1

  ports:

  - containerPort: 3000"

Я пытался добавлять ему
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
insecureSkipTLSVerify: true

Но мне всё равно выдает ошибку в argocd ui в events.
"IP/louislam/uptime-kuma:1": pinging container registry IP: Get "https://IP/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for IP because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Мне бы хотелось отключить эту проверку, сертификат был самоподписанный, я пытался его внедрять, но либо я делал что-то не так, либо просто не работает. Всё собрано локально, поэтому мне все равно на "безопасность", поэтому хотелось бы отключить эту проверку при пулле образа
